# Update Angular 14 to 15: mat-pseudo-checkbox not visible anymore

Tags: css, typescript, checkbox, angular-material, angular15

I have to update my web application from Angular 14 to 15, but I have a strange problem: my mat-pseudo-checkbox (code below) is not visible anymore.

```
<div>
   <mat-pseudo-checkbox (click)="itemSelect()" [state]="isItemSelected()"></mat-pseudo-checkbox>
Test
</div>
```

In Angular 14 the *"mat-pseudo-checkbox"* was visible. If I change the code with "mat-checkbox" the checkbox appears. I have not CSS relative the *"mat-pseudo-checkbox"* and I'm not able to find any information about porting from 14 to 15 for the *"mat-pseudo-checkbox"*.

How can I handle this properly?

Comment: I could not find a reference to `mat-pseudo-checkbox` anywhere on the documentation, are you sure this is a Angular Material component ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/selection/pseudo-checkbox/pseudo-checkbox.ts

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo checkbox should be imported in angular 15.

import { MatPseudoCheckboxModule } from "@angular/material/core";